# how to know $HOME in a .deb package

Tags: linux, package, dpkg

I am making a debian package that includes some libraries.
When installing the package, the libraries have to link to $HOME.

Here is a part of my postinst file:

```
ln -sf $INSTALLPATH/libtest.so $HOME/.config/test/libtest.so
```

If using dpkg command to install, linking works, but if installing package by Ubuntu Software Center, I can't find the link library under $HOME/.config/test.

Please let me know howto link libraries to $HOME using Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. A debian package always applies to the whole system and not just a single user. And it should not create or modify any files inside home directories.

Comment: Debian package should never rely on a home directory location for a specific user unless the package creates the user in case it doesn't exist. See http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/ and especially links referred therein.